# how to generate matching arms for an enum in proc macro

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

i have a enum like

```rust
#[derive(Normal)]
pub enum NormalError{
    #[msg = "{name} not found"]
    NotFound{name: &'static str},
    #[msg = "invalid {}"]
    InvalidParameter(&'static str),
    #[msg = "invalid"]
    InvalidCredential
}
```

and i want to make a proc macro to impl a function to print message like code below:

```rust
impl xxx for Normal{
    fn print(&self) -> String{
        match self{
            NormalError::NotFound{name} => format!("{name} not found"),
            NormalError::InvalidParameter(t) => format!("{} not found", t.0),
            NormalError::InvalidCredential => format!("invalid"),
        }
    }
}
```

but i failed to process the field of variant because the `syn::Field` cannot convert to `syn::Arm` easily. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe look at how `thiserror` is [implemented](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror-impl/1.0.50).

Comment: The `synstructure` crate makes this very easy.